# Animate HTML list next/prev fixed lenght

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having html list as ,

```
<button id="leftArrow" class="fbtnFirst">Left</button>
<button id="rightArrow" class="fbtnLast">Right</button>
<div id="itemsListBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/A/Letter-AThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/B/Letter-BThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/C/Letter-CThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/D/Letter-DThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/E/Letter-EThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/F/Letter-FThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/G/Letter-GThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://www.kids-pages.com/folders/alphabet/H/Letter-HThumb.jpg" border="1">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Want to display only three items at a time , and when user clicks on right/left button the next/previous three items will be displayed. And when list doesn't have altleast first/last three items black image will be displayed. The condition is that list should display atleast 3 items.

Here is my fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/9sLJQ/

Comment: What is the issue/question?

Comment: Want to display only three items at a time , and when user clicks on right/left button the next/previous three items will be displayed. And when list doesn't have altleast first/last three items black image will be displayed. The condition is that list should display atleast 3 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add `<li>` elements with black images to the end of the list so the length of the list is always a multiple of three?

Then change:

```
counter++;
```

To:

```
counter += showNum;
```

And change:

```
counter--;
```

To:

```
counter -= showNum;
```

Actually, if you just make the code changes, your fiddle works nicely without adding black images. Perhaps you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks , and what if want to make it in circular fashion ?

Comment: @Nishant - You may already have solved this, but here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sLJQ/5/).